# Creating a history table without using triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a TABLE A with 3000 records with 25 columns. I want to have  a history table called Table A history holding all the changes updates and deletes for me to look up any day. I usually use cursors. Now thought using triggers which I was not asked to. Do you have any other suggestions? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using tsql /SQL server and you can't use triggers, which is the only sure way to get every change, maybe use a stored procedure that is scheduled in job to run every x amount of time, the stored procedure using a MERGE statement with the two tables to get new records or changes. I would not suggest this if you need every single change without question.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA (id INT, Column1 nvarchar(30))
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA_History (id INT, Column1 nvarchar(30), TimeStamp DateTime)
```

(this code isn't production, just the general idea)
Put the following code inside a stored procedure and use a Sql Server Job with a schedule on it.

```
MERGE INTO dbo.TableA_History
USING dbo.TableA
ON TableA_History.id = TableA.id AND TableA_History.Column1 = TableA.Column1
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (id,Column1,TimeStamp) VALUES (TableA.id,TableA.Column1,GETDATE())
```

So basically if the record either doesn't exist or doesn't match meaning a column changed, insert the record into the history table.

Comment: Thank you. I totally agree triggers are the way. but thats a no :( here. thatsy!. do you have an example or was this answered before with a stored procedure? I would love to see an example. I created a cursor to capture changes and then scheduled as a job. But I would love to create something new with a merge!

Comment: SQL Server 2016 introduced support for system-versioned temporal tables as a database feature that brings built-in support for providing information about data stored in the table at any point in time rather than only the data that is correct at the current moment in time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank You DanB. this works for the one column. So i have to use for all the 25 columns in the table then..is it?

Comment: yup, your ON clause will join on all the 25 columns. I know it's a pain, but I do have some MERGES inside my data warehouse that do that sort of join. ON TableA_History.id = TableA.id AND TableA_History.Column1 = TableA.Column1 AND TableA_History.Column2 = TableA.Column2 etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create history without triggers in some case, even if you are not using SQL Server 2016 and system-versioned table are not available.

In some cases, when you can identify for sure which routines are modifying your table, you can create history using `OUTPUT INTO` [clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

For example,

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MainTable]
OUTPUT inserted.[]
      ,...
      ,'I'
      ,GETUTCDATE()
      ,@CurrentUserID
INTO [dbo].[HistoryTable]
SELECT *
FROM ... ;
```

In routines, when you are using `MERGE` I like that we can use `$action`:

> Is available only for the MERGE statement. Specifies a column of type
>   nvarchar(10) in the OUTPUT clause in a MERGE statement that returns
>   one of three values for each row: 'INSERT', 'UPDATE', or 'DELETE',
>   according to the action that was performed on that row.

It's very handy that we can add the `user` which is modifying the table. Using triggers you need to use session context or session variable to pass the `user`. In versioning table you need to add additional column to the main table in order to log the user as it only logs the current table columns (at least for now).

So, basically it depends on your data and application. If you have many sources of CRUD over the table, the trigger is the most secure way. If your table is very big and heavily used, using `MERGE` is not good as it my cause blocking and harm performance.

In our databases we are using all of the methods depending on the situation:

- triggers for legacy
- system-versioning for new development
- direct OUTPUT in the history, when sure that data is modified only by given set of routines